# Close div content for 1 hour

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently making a blog for one pets association and I want to hide my div content for 1 hour after I click on my close button.
I've found something similar on Stack Overflow but it didn't help.

**HTML**

```html
<div id="shownOnlyOnceHour">
  <div class="alert alert-warning">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">x</button>
    <p>Title :</p>
    <div id="contentlist1"">
      <div class="columnsl"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hidden content will only be hidden for the user who has hidden it. If someone else opens the blog, they will see it. Are you using ServeSide or APIs to solve this problem? Or do you really want to hide it only for the user who has hidden it?

Comment: no it's only for the user who clicks the close button to hide the content. Can be using cookies.  it can be an hour like a day for example. I am looking for the easiest way possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the time of clicking on the `close` button in `localStorage`:

```
document.querySelector(".close").addEventListener("click", function() {
  localStorage.setItem("lastTime", new Date().getTime());
  
  // Your code to hide the div
});
```

Then you can check if there is any field named `lastTime` in `localStorage` and compare the value with the current time:

```
var currentTime = new Date().getTime();

var lastTime = localStorage.getItem("lastTime");

if (lastTime !== undefined && ((currentTime - lastTime) * 1000 * 60 * 60) >= 1) {
  localStorage.removeItem("lastTime");
  //Your code to show the div
}
```

Let me know if you need any more clarification.

Comment: Hi,

Thank yuou for your help and sorry about late reply but are you sure about condition ?

Answer (score 0):

I think something's wrong or i don't get you..
I try it with adding my class="d-none" into shownOnlyOnceADay but doesn"t work.

```
var currentTime = new Date().getTime();

var lastTime = localStorage.getItem("lastTime");

if (lastTime !== undefined && ((currentTime - lastTime) * 1000 * 60 * 60) >= 1) {
  localStorage.removeItem("lastTime");
$("#shownOnlyOnceADay").removeClass('d-none');
}

<div id="shownOnlyOnceADay" class="d-none">
```

Comment: Did you set value in `localStorage`? If you did, can you console the output of `lastTime`

Comment: In the `if` condition, I am checking first if any value set to `lastItem` and then substracting the `lastTime` value from `currentTime` and multiplying the result by **1000 (milliseconds) * 60 (seconds) * 60 (minutes)**.

I don't see why it shouldn't work